# Optimal number of half-spaces in the $H$-representation of the convex hull of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, computer-science

Let $P$ be the polytope obtained as the convex hull of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^d$. This is the $V$-representation of $P$. Note that $P$ can also be represented as an intersection of closed half-spaces in $\mathbb R^d$. This is the $H$-representation of $P$.

> **Question.** *In terms of $n$ and $d$, what is a good upper-bound on the number of half-spaces in the smallest $H$-representation of $P$ ?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [Upper Bound Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_bound_theorem), the maximum number of $(d-1)$-dimensional faces of an $n$-vertex polytope is achieved by the cyclic polytopes.  This number can be explicitly written via the [Dehn-Sommerville equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn%E2%80%93Sommerville_equations).

Comment: Thanks. For the record, if $f_k(P)$ is the number of $k$-dimensional faces of $P$, then the referenced Dehn-Sommerville equations (combined with Upper Bound Theorem) yield $f_{d-1}(P) \le 2{n-(d+1)/2 \choose n-d}$.